# MySQL trigger error 1054

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `aio_mtltp` AFTER INSERT ON `master_table_ltp` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF (master_table_ltp.IMHQ_solicitada = 'Si') THEN
    INSERT INTO imhq(RECORD_ID, Tipo_de_Estudio, Año, Codigo_Interno, Iniciales_del_Px, Edad, Sexo)
    VALUES (NEW.RECORD_ID, NEW.Tipo_de_Estudio, NEW.Año, NEW.Codigo_Interno, NEW.Edad, NEW.Sexo, NEW.Iniciales_del_Px); 
END IF; 
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get ERROR:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Iniciales_del_Px' in 'NEW'
```

It looks good to me. Any ideas where I went wrong?

[Link to the table fields image](https://postimg.org/image/lzsg5jo85/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look real carefully at the following picture:

[image]

Comment: oh lord, MAN I need glasses. Thanks!